# How should I chose the function to be integrated in this complex integral question?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: CONTOUR INTEGRATION]

Please check this question and tell me have I done this question right.

1.I was confused how to chose z since in question we had given only that the contour is a circle of radius 1. so can i chose z(t) as I have for circle of any radius?

2. And as it can be seen that the contour is a closed one, so shouldn't its integration along the loop or circle be zero?

Comment: It looks pretty fine to me. +1

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title of what the problem is. It doesn't let people know what its about and so you are more likely to have people skip over your question.

Comment: @IanMiller I just edited it, hope my question is more clear now.

Comment: What do you mean by 'choose $z$'?

Comment: The integral is not zero because your function is not holomorphic.

Comment: @YuriyS  Question is : If C is the circle $ \mid Z \mid=1$ then evaluate the integral. and i want to know if have not give what function i have to integrate and just given that the contour is a circle with radius 1 can i chose the general equation : $z(t) = cos(t) + isin(t)$ and thus for circle of any radius can I chose this one function?